# Parsing 34Mb using JSON.parse take 45 seconds. Can it be improved?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

We're developing an app containing ~4000 recipes. For saving space, the recipes are only saved in one locale when downloading. A user may however change its locale in the app's setting. When this occurs, the app downloads the recipes in the new locale (around 34Mb). Once downloaded, the user may access the recipes in the new locale, but it takes 45 seconds each time they access the recipe section.

We found the culprit to be JSON.parse. We are aware that a 34Mb files may take some time parsing, but is there a way of improving the time? When accessing the recipes bundled with the app (the first locale) everything is fast and smooth, even tough the file is about the same size.

Here is the code that read the downloaded files and parse it:

```
const readDownloadedJson = async () => {
    await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs
      .readFile(recipesPath, "utf8")
      .then((res) => {
        const parsedJson = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(parsedJson.length);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("status: ", err.status);
        console.log("data: ", err.data);
        console.log("message: ", err.message);
      });
  };
```

Meanwhile, this is how the bundled recipes are called:

```
import Data from "../../Data/Recipes.json";
```

If it helps, we are using react-native 0.72.1 and react-native-blob-util 0.18.6

Comment: Break up the file into smaller pieces. How you do that depends on your app and audience. There must be some set of recipes that are hardly ever accessed -- those can go in a different file. Maybe each recipe is in its own file and you store key words in a hash file that points to the recipe file. There are many ways to crack that nut.

Comment: Don't store so much in a single JSON. Use a database.

Comment: Are you running a server? If so this is a good use-case for pagination. If not, and you've identified the culprit to be JSON.parse, then you could use other libraries that can parse the JSON faster, for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-parse

Comment: the reason the bundled code is faster is because there is no JSON parsing, it's already an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment of Heretic Monkey, we will split the big file into smaller chunks that will be loaded only when needed.